# Emberjs nothing handled this action

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dom-events, action

> Error : Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action 'rollDice'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.

I made sure that the method in the controller had the same name as the action.
???

**HTML portion**

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
     {{outlet}}
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
     {{#linkTo "roll"}}Lets roll dice!{{/linkTo}}
     </script>
     <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="roll">
        <p class="centerme">A Dice Roller.</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>Click to play!<br/>
        <button id="play" {{action 'rollDice'}}>Roll Dice</button>
    </p>
    <section id="roll-wrap">Dice stuff</section>
<script>
```

**Controller**

```
DiceRoller.RollController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    var diceModel = this.get('model');
    actions: {
        rollDice: function () {
            var x=[270,1080,1440,810];
            var rand1=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
            var rand2=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
            
            diceModel.set('rotateXvalue',x[rand1]+"deg");
            diceModel.set('rotateYvalue',x[rand2]+"deg");
            diceModel.save();
        }.property('diceModel.rotateXvalue','diceModel.rotateYvalue')
    }
});
```

**Routing**

```
DiceRoller.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("roll");
});

DiceRoller.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function(){
        this.transitionTo("roll");
    }
});

DiceRoller.DiceRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('Dice');
    }
});
```

**Model**

```
DiceRoller.Dice = DS.Model.extend({
rotateXvalue: DS.attr('string'),
rotateYvalue: DS.attr('string')
});

DiceRoller.Dice.FIXTURES = [
{

rotateXvalue: '40deg',
rotateYvalue: '37deg'
}
];
```

http://jsbin.com/qosujasi/1/
My JS bin, so far it gives me an error about setting the content of an object proxy.

Comment: Do you have a application template with an `{{outlet}}`?

Comment: Also, I thought that the DiceRoute in the router is what finds the model?

Comment: Since you're using /#/roll, your route would be `RollRoute` and you're controller would be `RollController`.  You can still use a dice model with this route, like in my example below.

Comment: I have changed the DiceRoute in my router.js to RollRoute. I used a fixture adapter to create a record for my model. It works because the values of the record provide the values of the CSS needed to render the dice. I just can't get the action event to work correctly, that is to change the values in the model so that the dice rolls.

Answer (score 2):

You've named your controller incorrectly.  The correct controller for the roll route would be `DiceRoller.RollController`.

In the `RollController`, you should get the model inside the `roleDice` action and you don't need the list of properties.  That's for computed properties, not actions.

```
DiceRoller.RollController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        rollDice: function () {
            var diceModel = this.get('model');
            var x=[270,1080,1440,810];
            var rand1=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
            var rand2=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);

            diceModel.set('rotateXvalue',x[rand1]+"deg");
            diceModel.set('rotateYvalue',x[rand2]+"deg");
            diceModel.save();
        }
    }
});
```

Check out [this jsBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gijeteha/1/edit).

You need to create the model record to be able to set values on it in your route, like this:

```
DiceRoller.RollRoute = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    model:function() {
        return this.store.createRecord('dice');
    }
});
```

Comment: I have editing the name of the controller, but the action is still not being handled. I think that a route is not being specified but I cannot find it.

Comment: I've updated my answer, try that and see if it works.

Comment: I had added the templates that I used. Ok, I see the reason behind not having the list of properties. I wanted the controller to create a new value of rotateXvalue, rotateYvalue and save it to the model, so that the dice is updated.

Comment: Where are you creating the dice model?

Comment: I checked out jsBin and replaced the code in RollController with console.log("Stuff"). I think what's happening is my file which contains the RollController is not properly being referenced.

Comment: I created the Dice Model in a file called DiceModel. That file is in the JS folder.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you're not creating the record in your route.  I've added an example to my answer.  Are you including each of your js files through script tags?

Answer (score 2):

I am fresh new to Ember.js and also struggling, but for me it worked to either move `actions: {...}` from controller to route:

```
DiceRoller.DiceRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('Dice');
    },
    actions: {...} // move actions here
});
```

**OR** to use `ApplicationController` instead of `RollController`:

```
DiceRoller.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    var diceModel = this.get('model');
    actions: {
        rollDice: function () {
            var x=[270,1080,1440,810];
            var rand1=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
            var rand2=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);

            diceModel.set('rotateXvalue',x[rand1]+"deg");
            diceModel.set('rotateYvalue',x[rand2]+"deg");
            diceModel.save();
        }.property('diceModel.rotateXvalue','diceModel.rotateYvalue')
    }
});
```

Not saying it is the correct way! Just saying it worked for me - still learning ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you follow Ember official tutorial, and get to the Templates->Actions chapter, you will probably run into this error on first example because this example uses Components that are explained later. I tried adding action to templates/about.hbs and creating component/about.js with action handler, but these two wouldn't work together. Im guessing the trick is to define hbs file in templates/components/ but before that I got the action working by creating 
controllers/about.js like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
isBody: false,
  actions: {
    toggleBody() {
        console.log("Look at me go!");
        this.toggleProperty('isBody');
    }
  }
});
```

This is EmberCli environment, v2.0.0 and they say Controllers and Components will merge into one thing soon, so...